# Stopping a System Sound from playing

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, avaudioplayer

I can turn off my audio player by using:

```
- (IBAction)sndOnOff:(id)sender {

    if (_sndBtn.selected == NO) {

        [_sndBtn setSelected:YES];
        [audioPlayer stop];
        }
        else{

        [_sndBtn setSelected:NO];
        [audioPlayer play];
    }
```

But how do I turn off a System Sound that I've created?

```
 NSURL *soundURL1 = [[NSBundle mainBundle] URLForResource:@"selectSound"
                                            withExtension:@"wav"];
 AudioServicesCreateSystemSoundID((__bridge CFURLRef)soundURL1, &sound2);
```

Comment: Can't you just avoid playing the sounds when you're in the state where you don't want sounds to play? You shouldn't be changing the device settings and can't do that anyways.

Comment: I wasn't being sarcastic, I'm trying to be helpful. It's true that you should not be changing the volume on the device to mute sounds in your app. If you are allowing the user to toggle sounds, there's no reason that you can't insert a check before you play a sound. If you centralize your sound playing to a single class then this check can be done in just one spot.

Comment: How can I do it then?

Answer (score 3):

There is a reason that we don't get fine control over system sound - because it is supposed to be short (in iOS < 30 seconds) and complete. Imagine, how many times do we experience a system sound cut-off in any OS?

But you could do this:

```
AudioServicesDisposeSystemSoundID (sound2);
```

to stop it. But this means you would need to create the sound again by using:

```
AudioServicesCreateSystemSoundID((__bridge CFURLRef)soundURL1, &sound2);
```

And to play it again:

```
AudioServicesPlaySystemSound(sound2);
```

You could of course instead to play your "system sound" on `AVPlayer` and stop it like you do a song, but that would mean it "shouldn't be" a system sound in the first place. Hope this helps.

Comment: The thing is the sounds also load up when the game starts!

Comment: @Jking Provide more information how you load your game and the sound, it would help us to help you further. Show the calling sequence.

Answer (score 0):

Just do this...

```
    AudioServicesDisposeSystemSoundID (sound2);
```

I cannot think of any negative consequences.